# Java Scanner with string input should be closed?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, sonar-runner

Sonar complains that the Scanner should always be closed, is it right?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("simple string")
```

This scanner is not scanning from file etc. Why should it be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `new Scanner("string")` it creates a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) which creates a character stream. So you have to close it.

[See the OpenJDK source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8cc500af2454/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l747)

```
public Scanner(String source) {
    this(new StringReader(source), WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
}
```

Comment: But does it _need_ to be closed? A `StringReader` doesn't appear to hold any resources that need to be released. Looking at the source code, the `close()` method simply sets the reference it has to the `String` to `null`.

Comment: @Slaw Probably not, but that is why Sonar complains since it implements the Closeable interfaces.

Comment: sorry but I really got confused, is it necessary to close or I will mark it as false positive and will not close ?

Comment: @user9449907 Close it to stay coherent.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in Sonar doc,

> Connections, streams, files, and other classes that implement the
>   Closeable interface or its super-interface, AutoCloseable, needs to be
>   closed after use.

And `Scanner` does implement `Closeable` interface. Hence it should be closed.

Refer this [link](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules?open=squid%3AS2095&rule_key=squid%3AS2095).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to close the Scanner, but it is better to do it in order to release the resources allocated for Scanner to optimize your code and make it faster and efficient.